# pysimplegui has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, pysimplegui

everithing was working without errors  then sudenly
idle gave this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\.py", line 28, in <module>
    [gui.Button('button3'), gui.text('text')]])
AttributeError: module 'PySimpleGUIWx' has no attribute 'text'
```

the code:

```
main_window = gui.Window('window').Layout([[gui.Button('button1'), gui.Button('button2')],
                                           [gui.Button('button3'), gui.text('text')]])
event, values = main_window.read()

while True:
    if event == gui.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'button3': 
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo -

```
.Layout([[gui.Button('button1'), gui.Button('button2')],
                                           [gui.Button('button3'), gui.text('text')]])
```

You forgot the `'`after button1

So python thinks text is a attribute rather than a string

Edit - If it was a typo in the formatting while asking, look at this, this will solve it.

This line- `gui.text('text')` should be `gui.Text('text')`

The .text must be capital `.Text()`

Comment: it was not the problem, i acsidently delete ' when i was writing the post

Comment: `gui.Text` is a class instance, so it follows camel casing

Answer (score 0):

```py
AttributeError: module 'PySimpleGUIWx' has no attribute 'text'
```

It should be typo error and Python is case sensitive, so it should be

```py
gui.Text('text')    # Not gui.text('text')
```